# File Access In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a web app and I want to store .pdf files in a folder outside the project root directory and still be able to access those files from the web app using the "a href" tags. How do I go about achieving this objective in Laravel?

Your assistance will surely be appreciated

Example

```
    some folder
        |---> web app
        |     |------> index.php
        |     |------> css
        |     |------> js
        |
        |---> file folder
```

Comment: using `_PATH` doesn't help?

Comment: Can I ask 1 question why are you not storing file in public folder ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a folder called `storage` that is at the root level of the laravel application that can handle this kind of thing.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Hey, I'm aware for the storage folder but what I want is to store the files  elsewhere and still be able to view them (pdf) from the app

Answer (score 0):

You can add a soft link to the directory or you can create a new folder inside `public` folder. The soft link needs to be a full path.

```
some folder
        |---> web app
        |     |------> pdfFolder/ (ln -s  to hiddenFolder) 
        |     |------> index.php
        |     |------> css
        |     |------> js
        |
        |---> hidefolder
```